# Add text over D3 node in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

So I have a JSON file called scratch that holds nodes and links...

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "name": "Guardians of the Galaxy",
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Chris Pratt"
    },
    {
      "name": "Vin Diesel"
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "source": "Guardians of the Galaxy",
      "target": "Chris Pratt"
    },
    {
      "source": "Guardians of the Galaxy",
      "target": "Vin Diesel"
    }
  ]
}
```

And I'm trying to have the name of each node hover over the node when it's loaded. The text is also extremely large.
Here is how I'm making the nodes

```
         const nodes_data = data['nodes'];

         let simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
              .nodes(nodes_data);

         simulation
             .force("charge_force", d3.forceManyBody())
             .force("center_force", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

         let node = svg.append("g")
         .attr("class", "nodes")
         .selectAll("circle")
         .data(nodes_data)
         .enter()
         .append("circle")
         .attr("r", 5)
         .attr("fill", "red");

         node.append("text")
            node.attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.name})`);

         simulation.on("tick", tickActions);

         function tickActions() {
    
                    node
                        .attr("cx", function (d) {
                            return d.x;
                        })
                        .attr("cy", function (d) {
                            return d.y;
                        });
         }
```

Note: I now know that the text is stuck in the top left because of the .attr("x/y"...), I just don't know how to get it smaller and over the nodes.

```
            let text = svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "nodes")
                .selectAll("text")
                .data(nodes_data)
                .enter()
                .append("text")
                .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x })
                .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y })
                .text(function(d) { return d.name });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure node labels are always above nodes, first create separate layers for both and make sure the label layer is added after the nodes' one.
To make labels smaller, just set **font-size**:

```
const nodetLayer = svg.append('g');
const textLayer = svg.append('g');
...
const texts = textLayer.selectAll('text')
  .data(nodes_data)
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  .attr('font-size', `${your-font-size}px`)
...
const nodes = nodelayer.selectAll('circle')
  .data(nodes_data)
  .enter()
  .append('circle')
```

Alternatively, you can create a **<g>** element per node and append a **<circle>** and a **<text>** to it.

Comment: So for some reason whenever I load in the data, the x and y coordinates are changed from what they should be whenever the 'd3.forceSimulation()' the x,y coords go from being in the 200's to somewhere within the range ([-20,20], 0) @Michael Rovinsky

Comment: I suppose it's because they are translated by zoom / pan. Do you use d3 zoom() ?